# Can this probability be obtained by a combinatorial/symmetry argument?

Tags: co.combinatorics, pr.probability, gr.group-theory, probability-distributions, enumerative-combinatorics

Suppose that $a_1,\dots,a_n,b_1,\dots,b_n$ are iid random variables each with a symmetric non-atomic distribution.
Let $p$ denote the probability that there is some real $t$ such that $t a_i \ge b_i$ for all $i$.
It [was shown](https://mathoverflow.net/a/415074/36721) that
$$p=\frac{n+1}{2^n}.$$

Can this be proved by a combinatorial/symmetry argument?

Comment: What is your intuitive understanding as to why the answer is not simply $1/2^n$?

Comment: @thedude : If you look at the existing proof of this result, you can see that $1/2^n$ is just the probability (say) that all $a_i$'s are $<0$, and for such $a_i$'s one can easily find a good $t$. But, of course, there are other possibilities for a good $t$ to exist.

Comment: @thedude : Now there is a complete answer -- below -- to your question (which is also an answer to my question)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If I understand correctly, $c_i := b_i/a_i$ should also be symmetric and non-atomic.
Then the result holds if there exists $t$ so that for all $i$

- $t \geq c_i$ if $a_i > 0$;
- $c_i \geq t$ if $a_i < 0$.

Reorder the indices so that $|c_1| < |c_2| < \dots < |c_n|$.
There are $2^n$ ways to assign signs to $a_i$ for each $i \in [n]$.
The only assignments for which an appropriate $t$ exists are those where the signs of $a_1,\dots,a_k$ are positive and the signs of $a_{k+1},\dots,a_n$ are negative with $k \in \{0,1,2,\dots,n\}$.
There are $n+1$ such assignments, so the desired probability is $(n+1)/2^n$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!

Comment: This is similar to a classic problem (I don't know its provenance) that appears for instance at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/325141.